# Tweak Export-PowerBIReport to download file to Azure Data Lake(GEN2)

Tags: powershell, powerbi, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am using Export-PowerBIReport to download PBIX file as below, however, I think in -Outfile we can only specify our local folder location

```
Export-PowerBIReport -Id TestID -OutFile .\TestReport.pbix
```

Is there a way in which we can give path of Azure Data Lake. Here is what I have tried so far.

1. Established connection with storage account as below:

$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName '' -StorageAccountKey ''

The connection was successful.

2. Tried giving path of lake as below

   Export-PowerBIReport -Id TestID -OutFile https://mytestlake.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/test.pbix

I am stuck on how we can specify the path to the lake in Export-PowerBIReport report. I get below issue when I run above command:

```
Export-PowerBIReport : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'https' does not exist.
```

Comment: Did you try to export your file in a temp folder then upload it through New-AzDataLakeGen2Item (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-powershell#upload-a-file-to-a-directory)

Comment: I will not be having a temporary folder, as I am planning to run the script from Azure Portal.